# Unable to apply onChange event on dynamic table

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp

The onChange event does not working on dynamic table, it will read the data of the table on page load. After edit the data, it will read data before editing instead of showing the edited data.
Here my code:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">  
    $('#tableDat1').on("change",function(){
    // $('#tableBody').change(function() {

 var TableData = new Array();
   $('#tableDat1 tr' ).each(function(row, tr){
    TableData[row]={  
        "productName" : $(tr).find('td:eq(0)').text()
        //"productName" : $(this).find('td:eq(0)').text(); 
        , "instance_name" : $(tr).find('td:eq(1)').text()
        , "steps" :$(tr).find('td:eq(2)').text()
        , "workAround" : $(tr).find('td:eq(3)').text()
        , "resolution" : $(tr).find('td:eq(4)').text()
         , "startingImpactDate" : $(tr).find('td:eq(5)').text()
          , "endImpactDate" : $(tr).find('td:eq(6)').text()
           , "comments" : $(tr).find('td:eq(7)').text()
    }
   // console.log("table data is",TableData);
    var abc = JSON.stringify(TableData)
   // $("#aa").val(abc);
    document.getElementById("aa").value = abc;
}); 
 TableData.shift();
console.log("table data is a",TableData);
 });

<div class="container">
 <table id="tableDat1" class="table-hover table table-bordered table 
 table-striped">
  <thead>
   <tr>
  <th>Product Name</th>
  <th scope="col">Instance NAme</th>
  <th scope="col">Steps</th>
  <th scope="col">WorkAround</th>
  <th scope="col">Resolution</th>
  <th scope="col">Starting Impact Date</th>
  <th scope="col">End Impact Date</th>
  <th scope="col">Comments</th>
  <!-- <th scope="col">Edit/Update</th> -->
   </tr>
  </thead>
   <tbody id="tbd">
     <c:forEach var="tableDatum" items="${list18}">
  <tr>  <td><textarea  id="echoText" rows="8" cols="15"  
 class="tableBody"> <c:out value="${tableDatum.productName}"/></textarea> 
  </td>
```

[this is a screen shot of created table for your reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jlq00.png)

Sample table HTML code:-

```
<table  class="table-hover ">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Product Name</th>
            <th scope="col">Instance NAme</th>
            <th scope="col">Steps</th>
            <th scope="col">WorkAround</th>
            <th scope="col">Resolution</th>
            <th scope="col">Starting Impact Date</th>
            <th scope="col">End Impact Date</th>
            <th scope="col">Comments</th>
            <!-- <th scope="col">Edit/Update</th>-->
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="tbd" class="tbd1">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <textarea  id="echoText" rows="8" cols="15"  class="tableBody">NOTE: In the case where the width attribute is set in more than one cell in the same column, the largest width is the one that is applied. Likewise, if the content in any table cell in that column (such as a graphic) outsizes a specified width, the width of the content will establish the width of the cell and the column it resides in.</textarea>
            </td>
            <td>
                <textarea rows="8" cols="15" class="datTable">IBM2</textarea>
            </td>
            <td>
                <textarea rows="8" cols="15"></textarea>
            </td>
            <td>
                <textarea rows="8" cols="15"></textarea>
            </td>
            <td>
                <textarea rows="8" cols="15"></textarea>
            </td>
            <td>
                <textarea rows="8" cols="15"></textarea>
            </td>
            <td>
                <textarea rows="8" cols="15"></textarea>
            </td>
            <td>
                <textarea rows="8" cols="15"></textarea>
            </td>
        </tr>


        <tr>
            <td>
                <textarea  id="echoText" rows="8" cols="15"  class="tableBody"></textarea>
            </td>
            <td>
                <textarea rows="8" cols="15" class="datTable">IBM</textarea>
            </td>
            <td>
                <textarea rows="8" cols="15">1</textarea>
            </td>
            <td>
                <textarea rows="8" cols="15">Anna</textarea>
            </td>
            <td>
                <textarea rows="8" cols="15">Debbie</textarea>
            </td>
            <td>
                <textarea rows="8" cols="15">res</textarea>
            </td>
            <td>
                <textarea rows="8" cols="15">sit</textarea>
            </td>
            <td>
                <textarea rows="8" cols="15">eit</textarea>
            </td>

        </tr>


        <tr>
            <td>
                <textarea  id="echoText" rows="8" cols="15"  class="tableBody"></textarea>
            </td>
            <td>
                <textarea rows="8" cols="15" class="datTable">3,ROAR</textarea>
            </td>
            <td>
                <textarea rows="8" cols="15">IBM</textarea>
            </td>
            <td>
                <textarea rows="8" cols="15"></textarea>
            </td>
            <td>
                <textarea rows="8" cols="15"></textarea>
            </td>
            <td>
                <textarea rows="8" cols="15"></textarea>
            </td>
            <td>
                <textarea rows="8" cols="15"></textarea>
            </td>
            <td>
                <textarea rows="8" cols="15"></textarea>
            </td>

        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: How is the table supposed to fire the `change` event? According to the W3C Spec, only inputs are supposed to trigger those events...

Comment: Just use other way of binding: `$('#tableDat1').on("change", "textarea", function(){ ... })`

Comment: thanks for your help but its not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will ask to change table `id` to `class` (as jQuery will not recognize multiple same `id`) and then do like below:-

```
$(document).find('.table-hover').on('keyup', 'textarea',function(){
  var TableRecords = new Array();
  var obj = $(this).closest('.table-hover');
  obj.find('tbody tr').each(function(){
      var datObj = {  
          "productName"           :   $(this).find('td:eq(0) textarea').val(),
          "instance_name"         :   $(this).find('td:eq(1) textarea').val(),
          "steps"                 :   $(this).find('td:eq(2) textarea').val(),
          "workAround"            :   $(this).find('td:eq(3) textarea').val(),
          "resolution"            :   $(this).find('td:eq(4) textarea').val(),
          "startingImpactDate"    :   $(this).find('td:eq(5) textarea').val(),
          "endImpactDate"         :   $(this).find('td:eq(6) textarea').val(),
          "comments"              :   $(this).find('td:eq(7) textarea').val(),
      }
      TableRecords.push(datObj);
  });
  console.log(TableRecords);
});
```

***Working snippet:-***

```js
$(document).find('.table-hover').on('keyup', 'textarea',function(){
  var TableRecords = new Array();
  var obj = $(this).closest('.table-hover');
  obj.find('tbody tr').each(function(){
      var datObj = {  
          "productName"           :   $(this).find('td:eq(0) textarea').val(),
          "instance_name"         :   $(this).find('td:eq(1) textarea').val(),
          "steps"                 :   $(this).find('td:eq(2) textarea').val(),
          "workAround"            :   $(this).find('td:eq(3) textarea').val(),
          "resolution"            :   $(this).find('td:eq(4) textarea').val(),
          "startingImpactDate"    :   $(this).find('td:eq(5) textarea').val(),
          "endImpactDate"         :   $(this).find('td:eq(6) textarea').val(),
          "comments"              :   $(this).find('td:eq(7) textarea').val(),
      }
      TableRecords.push(datObj);
  });
  console.log(TableRecords);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table  class="table-hover ">
 <thead>
  <tr>
   <th>Product Name</th>
   <th scope="col">Instance NAme</th>
   <th scope="col">Steps</th>
   <th scope="col">WorkAround</th>
   <th scope="col">Resolution</th>
   <th scope="col">Starting Impact Date</th>
   <th scope="col">End Impact Date</th>
   <th scope="col">Comments</th>
   <!-- <th scope="col">Edit/Update</th>-->
  </tr>
 </thead>
 <tbody id="tbd" class="tbd1">
  <tr>
   <td>
    <textarea  id="echoText" rows="8" cols="15"  class="tableBody">NOTE: In the case where the width attribute is set in more than one cell in the same column, the largest width is the one that is applied. Likewise, if the content in any table cell in that column (such as a graphic) outsizes a specified width, the width of the content will establish the width of the cell and the column it resides in.</textarea>
   </td>
   <td>
    <textarea rows="8" cols="15" class="datTable">IBM2</textarea>
   </td>
   <td>
    <textarea rows="8" cols="15"></textarea>
   </td>
   <td>
    <textarea rows="8" cols="15"></textarea>
   </td>
   <td>
    <textarea rows="8" cols="15"></textarea>
   </td>
   <td>
    <textarea rows="8" cols="15"></textarea>
   </td>
   <td>
    <textarea rows="8" cols="15"></textarea>
   </td>
   <td>
    <textarea rows="8" cols="15"></textarea>
   </td>
  </tr>


  <tr>
   <td>
    <textarea  id="echoText" rows="8" cols="15"  class="tableBody"></textarea>
   </td>
   <td>
    <textarea rows="8" cols="15" class="datTable">IBM</textarea>
   </td>
   <td>
    <textarea rows="8" cols="15">1</textarea>
   </td>
   <td>
    <textarea rows="8" cols="15">Anna</textarea>
   </td>
   <td>
    <textarea rows="8" cols="15">Debbie</textarea>
   </td>
   <td>
    <textarea rows="8" cols="15">res</textarea>
   </td>
   <td>
    <textarea rows="8" cols="15">sit</textarea>
   </td>
   <td>
    <textarea rows="8" cols="15">eit</textarea>
   </td>

  </tr>


  <tr>
   <td>
    <textarea  id="echoText" rows="8" cols="15"  class="tableBody"></textarea>
   </td>
   <td>
    <textarea rows="8" cols="15" class="datTable">3,ROAR</textarea>
   </td>
   <td>
    <textarea rows="8" cols="15">IBM</textarea>
   </td>
   <td>
    <textarea rows="8" cols="15"></textarea>
   </td>
   <td>
    <textarea rows="8" cols="15"></textarea>
   </td>
   <td>
    <textarea rows="8" cols="15"></textarea>
   </td>
   <td>
    <textarea rows="8" cols="15"></textarea>
   </td>
   <td>
    <textarea rows="8" cols="15"></textarea>
   </td>

  </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
```